# Use settings.xml in Java

Tags: java, maven, system.xml

I have a Maven project and I tried to extract sensitive information from my code using ~/.m2/settings.xml. As far as I can tell from checking with the `mvn -X` command, the file can be read from.
This is my file:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <id>camera</id>
            <properties>
                <camera.url>some url</camera.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

I have tried getting the value from camera.url in my code using pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <camera.url>${camera.url}</camera.url>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

And then I am trying to retrieve the value in code using `System.getProperty("camera.url")`, but this returns null.
I can't seem to figure out what I have done wrong.

Comment: Just try to replace `systemPropertyVariables` with `systemProperties` and recheck?